# Cinnamon 2.2 How to add custom shortuct: move workspace up

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I'm quite aware this must have been asked many times, but I cannot seem to find the right search terms to get an answer.

I would like to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> move my workspace up, and similarly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to move down. Currently when I use these shortcuts cinnamon shows all the available workspaces or goes into expo mode. How do I change this?

Comment: Have you tried setting these in cinammon's settings?

Comment: Yes. There is no option to assign for any 'shift workspace up' type function.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no "Up" really. They may be displayed stacked in expo mode but that depends on how many you have defined. Anyway, you should be able to set this in Cinnamon Settings. You need to find the "Keyboard" section and choose the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab:

[image]

[image]

Change the shortcuts for "Switch to left workspace" and "Switch to right workspace" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> respectively and you should get what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. My workspaces are set in a 4 by 4 grid, so there is "up". But you have correctly highlighted my problem in that there is no up option, although my workspaces are structured such that there should be. I used to be able to use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Up` before a recent cinnamon update.

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes late, and will maybe not 100% answer the initial request. However, the basic feature can be obtain by using a specific applet (using it now with 3.0, used it in previous versions of Cinnamon as well): [Workspace grid (2D) and switcher](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/116).

When active and added to a panel, this applet actually lets you define a “real” workspace grid (number of rows / number of columns), and provides an option to “Use Keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down)” to switch desktop rows”. With this option checked, it actually overrides shortcuts for “Toggle Expo” and “Toggle Scale” to switch between workspaces (and you will be able to move windows to workspace up/down with `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+Up/Down`).

Note however that it seems to be possible to still keep the option to have shortcuts for Expo/Scale, looking at the comments on the applets page.

> Ok, so simply replacing 'switch-to-workspace-up' and 'switch-to-workspace-down' by 'switch-to-workspace-11' and 'switch-to-workspace-12' in the "applet.js"-file , assigning shortcuts to them via "keyboard shortcuts" in "system settings" and checking the "Use Keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down) to switch desktop rows" option in the applet settings got everything to work. Now I can specify shortcuts for expo/scale and move up/down separately. Nice!